# Query mongodb with UTC format date as filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongodb-query

I have 1 million+ record in MongoDB database and need to query records, such that their date field contains a value which is not in the last 30 days. The problem is it's present in UTCString() format and comparison in this format is not working.

Date in database looks like this -
"Tue, 06 Apr 2021 23:22:43 GMT"

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. For a query "< last 30 days" you must convert them to proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

instead of querying using the UTC date, use can use the Unix version of the date eg. use 1616284800000 instead of 2021-03-21T00:00:000Z

So your query will look like this

> db.Collection.find({"dateField":{$lte:new Date(1616284800000)}})

Also if you haven't already tried this you can

> db.Collection.find({"dateField":{$lte:ISODate("2021-03-21T00:00:00.000Z")}})

Comment: Hi, It's not working. Date is stored in the mongodb in UTCString format and it's costly to change it as there are 1 million + records. I think your solution works if date in mongodb is stored in Date format.